# Uncaught typeError

Tags: javascript, jquery

An unusual javascript error occurred can anybody help me to solve this issue? This is my whole function

```
$scope.getAllSubMilestones = function() {
    if (typeof $scope.subMilestones == 'undefined' || $scope.subMilestones.length < 0 || $scope.subMilestones == '') {
        // the array is defined and has at least one element
        var URL = $window.sessionStorage.getItem('HOST_URL') + '/subMilestoneFormObjs';

        function onSuccess(response) {
            $scope.subMilestones = response.data;
            pu_ws_counter++;
            setTimeout(function() {

                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.subMilestones.length; i++) {
                    var sub_milestone = $scope.subMilestones[i];

                        for(var k = 0; k < $scope.project.projectMileStones.length; k++) {
                            var pm = $scope.project.projectMileStones[k];
                            var selected_sub_milestone = pm.projectSubMileStones;

                        for (var j = 0; j < selected_sub_milestone.length; j++) {
                            var s = selected_sub_milestone[j];
                            if (sub_milestone.id == s.subMilestone.id) {
                                //document.getElementById('#' + sub_milestone.id).checked = true;
                                //                                                $('#' + sub_milestone.id).prop('checked', true);
                                $('#' + sub_milestone.id).click();
                            }
                        }
                        }
                    }

            }, 1000);
            $("#mydiv").hide();

        };
```

The line showing error is

> for(var k = 0; k < $scope.project.projectMileStones.length; k++)

Error says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: what is  `$scope.project.projectMileStones` ? It is probably not set.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if (typeof $scope.subMilestones == 'undefined' || $scope.subMilestones.length < 0 || $scope.subMilestones == '') {` returns `true` if `$scope.subMilestones` is `undefined`, but your comment underneath that states that the if should return `true` if it IS defined.. Try changing the `if` statement to the following:

`if (!(typeof $scope.subMilestones == 'undefined' || $scope.subMilestones.length < 0 || $scope.subMilestones == '')) {`

Let us know if that works!

Answer (score 0):

try to print **$scope.project.projectMileStones** in console.
there are strong chances that object $scope.project does not have **projectMileStones** property or **projectMileStones** is not type array.

Comment: it an array , it is showing me object present in it